# Is it a feature envy code smell if a state class within the state design pattern uses a field object of the context class to call a method?

Tags: python, state-pattern

I am using the state design pattern where I have a context class and a bunch of state classes. The context class has as class fields the state itself and also a few objects that are instances of other classes that the context class has. These objects have methods that I need to call within the context class but their calling depends on the state thus the behavior of the context class will be different per state as the purpose of this design pattern is.

My context class looks something like this:

```
class Context:
    def __init__(self, obj1, obj2):  
        self.state = StateOne(self)
        self.obj1 = obj1 
        self.obj2 = obj2
```

Then in the states classes I need to access methods that belong to the `obj1` and `obj2`. I don't know whether to do that in the context class itself or call them directly in the state classes:

```
# OPTION 1: calling them in the context class directly
def method_obj1(self):
   self.obj1.do_method()
```

and then call that inside the state class

```
class StateOne:  
    def __init__(self, context)
        self.context = context
                               
    def behaviour1(self)
        self.context.method_obj1()
```

Or I do this which I am not sure if this is feature envy code smell:

```
# OPTION 2: calling directly the object field in the state class 
class StateOne:
    def __init__(self, context)
        self.context = context

    def behaviour1(self):
        self.context.ob1.do_method()
```

Or maybe both of these options are wrong? I am simply finding it hard to grasp this clearly in order to decide how to implement this desired behaviour.

Comment: Both are ok in the short term. Certainly the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) implies that `OPTION 1` is approved.

Comment: I don't see the point in defining `StateOne` in the first place. In languages without first-class functions, you need an instance with a method that wraps the function. In Python, you can just assign `self.state = self.method_obj1` directly.

Comment: @quamrana Yes, Law of Demeter is exactly why I am unsure. The issue is that I will end up with a lot of wrapper methods then.

Comment: You just need to try it and work out which option gives you the easiest maintenance if the names `opt1` etc or `do_method()` were to change.

Comment: @chepner the need for a lot of these OOP patterns is obviated by first class functions

Comment: Feature envy is when you make *excessive* use of fields of another object. Occasional accesses to public fields are OK. There's no objective dividing line, but if you find yourself repeatedly doing the same calculations, that should probably be a method of the context class.